# Trouble viewing my website via external ip

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm trying to set up my first publicly view-able website but I've run into trouble.

**Here's the background info**

I've installed Apache Server on my Windows 7 machine using XAMPP binaries and I'm able to view the XAMPP sample webpage by visiting localhost in my browser.

After some research on the web, I discovered that, in order to make the website accessible outside of my local network, I needed to forward router traffic on port 80 to my local machine.

Viewing my router settings I see that my machine is on 192.168.1.3 so I forward port 80 traffic to 192.168.1.3:80. In order to verify that my website is actually addressed (internally) by 192.168.1.3:80, I entered '192.168.1.3' into a browser and I'm directed to the XAMPP sample website as expected.

**Here's where the trouble comes in**

When I attempt to connect to '192.168.1.3' from my phone (connected to the same network as my server) I'm unable to reach my website.

When I attempt to connect to my external ip address (as shown by whatsmyip.org and on my router settings page) I get 'This website is not available' due to a time out.

**Here's what I've tried**

After a bunch of research across the web I've tried a few things. I read that some firewalls or routers might block traffic on port 80, so I downloaded a utility from portforward.com to check if a given port was open. It indicated that port 80 was closed.

I entered the windows firewall settings and created a new inbound rule to allow traffic on port 80 and then ran the port-checking utility again. This time it said that port 80 was open! However, this didn't seem to make a difference. Both of the 'troubles' that I described still persist.

**Edit 1**

At the suggestion of Pekka, I checked to see if port 80 was open externally through my router. I used YouGetSignal.com to find out that it was actually **closed**.

I've been researching ways to open that port on my router (Actiontec Mi424WR) but each article I read just explains how to add a port-forwarding entry which I've already done.

**Edit 2**

To configure port forwarding I set the following parameters in my router's port forwarding table:

```
Destination Device: 192.168.1.3:80 (internal ip address of my server device)
Protocol: TCP
Forwarded Ports: 80
WAN Connection Type: All Broadband Devices
Status: Active
```

I'm not sure why YouGetSignal/CanYouSeeMe show port 80 as closed while this port forwarding entry seems to be active.

**Edit 3**

Thanks to Lea's comment about turning off windows firewall for debugging, I was able to identify that the issue **was** with the firewall. There was an entry that was blocking the Apache server executable (httpd.exe) on public connections. After changing the entry to Allow, everything worked as expected!

Comment: Is port 80 open to the public on the router as well?

Comment: A quick google led me to 'Open Port Check Tool' which indicated that it was closed!

Comment: Based on the details of your question, you did everything that you supposed to do. I guess, you failed (somehow) forwarding the port, that is why the port 80 is not responding.

Comment: Thanks, Lea. I've deleted and re-added the port forwarding entry a few times now. I'll edit the post to show how exactly I went about setting it

Comment: Do you have Windows Firewall ON? Turn OFF just for troubleshoot purpose and try again.

Comment: I turned it off and was able to successfully connect! After that, I knew it had to be an issue inside Windows Firewall and I was able to locate an entry that was blocking the Apache server executable for public connections. Thanks for the tips, Lea and Pekka

Answer (score 0):

From the machine running the server, search `what is my ip` on google (http://google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip). It will show your public IP address, use that to access your web server from your mobile phone.

192.168.*.* are private IP addresses. They can only be accessed from devices on same local network.

Comment: I think that the devices **are** on the same local network. They're connected to the same wifi network. I tried the external IP from my phone as well, but didn't get a response.